# Algorithm for randomly creating an Amaze level - what makes it beatable?

Tags: algorithms

For those of you who are not familiar with Amaze, here is some footage which will probably explain it better than I ever could: https://youtu.be/_puK8GS0-mA?t=192

For fun, I recreated it in a console application. I got the simple game mechanics to work correctly; it wasn't very difficult. I intended to also make a random level generator, but I realized that I don't know how to guarantee that it can be completed. My current method of level creation is very random, and leaves various areas that can't be reached because of situations like this,

```
# # # # # # #
# x - - - - #
# # # - # # #
# # # - # # #
# # # # # # #
```

where 'x' is the player, '#' is a wall, and '-' is open. You can never reach the bottom branch, but at the moment, my level generating code doesn't know that.

How could you make an algorithm that would know that the level it is creating is 100 percent beatable (i.e. you could reach every '-') and would be perfectly scalable?

Sorry for the lack of terminology.
Thanks for reading.

Also, am I posting in the right place?

Comment: Graph theory seems appropriate: the squares where the ball can go and stop are the nodes of the graph, and a node leads to another if the ball can go from one and stop at the other (so the graph is directed). You're looking for levels such that there's a path from the start to the end (in the corresponding graph). Lookup BFS and DFS.

Comment: It would be really hard to model this as a graph.  I think you just have to keep track of all of the states you can reach including which floor sections are painted and either win when everything is painted or lose when you've run out untested new states.  Anyway, a coding group would probably be more productive about those challenges than we would be -- math isn't going to make your model any better IMO.

Comment: Thanks, you guys.

Comment: You can use a depth first search to label the connected components. If there are more than one then the maze is unsolvable as is and must be modified.